# C++ Valgrind FIX Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, enums, memory-leaks, initialization, valgrind

I run my program using valgrind like this:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out < in0.txt > out0.txt
```

and get the following output:

```
==13077== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13077== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13077== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13077== Command: ./a.out
==13077==
==13077== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13077==    at 0x40491F: OnGetMostViewedClasses (in /home/user/a.out)
==13077==    by 0x404498: parser (in /home/user/a.out)
==13077==    by 0x404263: main (in /home/user/a.out)
==13077==
==13077==
==13077== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13077==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13077==   total heap usage: 90 allocs, 90 frees, 6,200 bytes allocated
==13077==
==13077== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13077==
==13077== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13077== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==13077== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
-bash-4.2$
```

while it refers to `StatusType res;` used in here:

```
static errorType OnGetMostViewedClasses(void* DS, const char* const command) {
    int numOfClasses;
    int *courses = NULL, *classes = NULL;
    StatusType res;

    ValidateRead(sscanf(command, "%d", &numOfClasses), 1, "%s failed.\n", commandStr[GETMOSTVIEWEDCLASSES_CMD]);
    if (numOfClasses > 0) {
        courses = (int *)malloc(numOfClasses * sizeof(int));
        classes = (int *)malloc(numOfClasses * sizeof(int));
        if (courses == NULL || classes == NULL) {
            res = ALLOCATION_ERROR;
        }
    }

    if (res != ALLOCATION_ERROR) {
        res = GetMostViewedClasses(DS, numOfClasses, courses, classes);
    }

    if (res != SUCCESS) {
        printf("%s: %s\n", commandStr[GETMOSTVIEWEDCLASSES_CMD], ReturnValToStr(res));
        if (courses != NULL) free(courses);
        if (classes != NULL) free(classes);
        return error_free;
    }

    printf("%s: %s\n", commandStr[GETMOSTVIEWEDCLASSES_CMD], ReturnValToStr(res));

    printf("Course\t|\tClass\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfClasses; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t|\t%d\n", courses[i], classes[i]);
    }

    printf("--End of most viewed classes--\n");

    if (courses != NULL) free(courses);
    if (classes != NULL) free(classes);

    return error_free;
}
```

and declared like this:

```
typedef enum {
    SUCCESS = 0,
    FAILURE = -1,
    ALLOCATION_ERROR = -2,
    INVALID_INPUT = -3
} StatusType;
```

**So my question is,** how can I solve this problem **without** changing the above code since it was given to us and my professor told: "you aren't allowed to change it" and "any errors found by valgrind will get you a mark of 0"?

Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed.

please note: except this problem I have 0 memory leak issue *(According to 32 input files I tested)*

Comment: Can you compile this code with debug information enabled (for g++, that's the -g flag), so valgrind can tell us which line it is complaining about? It's not showing any line numbers here. We may also need to see the calling function (`parser`) to answer this. i.e., are DS and command pointing to initialized memory?

Comment: "DS and command pointing to initialized memory?" yes I'm sure about that, I compiled it with g++ at the beginning (The one published here without g++), and valgrind showed me the following line "StatusType res;"

Answer (score 0):

Neither `res` nor `numOfClasses` is initialized. There are code paths that can result in these values being used in `if` statements without having a value assigned to them. `scanf` can fail, leaving `numOfClasses` uninitialized, and unless an error occurs in memory allocation `res` will not be assigned a value.

The solution is to initialize both:

```cpp
int numOfClasses = 0;
StatusType res = SUCCESS;
```

Comment: OP asked how to fix this without changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

As @1201ProgramAlarm points out, res is not initialized, and since it only gets set if numOfClasses is greater than zero and one of the malloc calls fails, you would need to somehow force the code into that code path. So, make sure the sscanf reads a value from command (command should be "1" or something like that), and then ... somehow cause malloc to return NULL. That's not trivial, but maybe you can add a clever line like `#define malloc(x) NULL` somewhere above that function? This entire exercise seems pretty terrible, TBH.

Edit: Alternatively, make malloc fail by asking for TOO MUCH memory. If numOfClasses is something like SIZE_MAX/sizeof(int), there's a pretty good chance you won't be able to allocate two blocks of memory that big, and one or both malloc calls will return NULL. That sets the res variable, and there won't be an uninitialized read. Stupid, stupid, stupid.

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged C++, but the code, with typedef enum, void*, malloc, printf and scanf smells badly of C. That is not a good way to learn C++.

You don't provide a definition of ValidateRead. You might just be able to subvert the preprocessor to do what you need, but this will be tortuous.

What the code really should do is `res = ValidateRead(...` where ValidateRead is a function that returns SUCCESS or INVALID_INPUT.